# Inicialização de variáveis em Java

Tags: java, variáveis, tipagem, inicialização, princípios-de-programação

Boa noite folks!

Estou aprendendo java, e se puderem me ajudar com essa dúvida...

Eu vi em um curso que estou fazendo, em um livro que estou lendo, e em sites onde pesquisei sobre esse assundo a mesma declaração, que é mais ou menos isso:
"As variáveis de instância de tipo primitivo são inicializadas por padrão, as variáveis dos tipos byte, char, short, int, long, float e double são inicializadas como 0" - DevMedia(https://www.devmedia.com.br/tipos-de-dados-por-valor-e-por-referencia-em-java/25293)

No entando, esse código me mostra um erro:

```
int a;
System.out.println("Valor de a: " + a);
```

No caso do eclipse, ele acusa esse erro:

> The local variable a may not have been initialized

Se o valor padrão de tipos primitivos numéricos é zero, porque eu preciso explicitamente inicializar uma variável deste mesmo tipo? No caso deste exemplo:

```
int a = 0;
```

O javac puro também acusa esse mesmo erro. Vocês sabem porque o compilador se comporta dessa maneira ?

Comment: O compilador se comporta dessa maneira em cumprimento a determinação expressa das especificações do Java, as quais determinam que *Para cada acesso a uma variável local x, x deve ter sido inicializada antes do acesso, do contrário, um erro de compilação irá ocorrer* [tradução minha, adaptada]. Fonte: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como na própria descrição que você postou, apenas as **variáveis de instância**, também chamadas de atributos, possuem valores padrão.

Variáveis de instancia seriam as variáveis definidas a nível da classe, e não no escopo de uma função. Por exemplo:

```
class Saldo {
    public int reais;    // <-- atributo, possui valor padrão
    public int centavos; // <-- atributo, possui valor padrão
}
```

Se eu criar uma instancia dessa classe `var saldo = new Saldo()`, eu não preciso inicializar manualmente esses atributos `reais` e `centavos`, eles terão o valor padrão 0.

No entanto para uma variável declarada num escopo local de uma função, ela precisa ser inicializada antes de ser acessada, como no seu próprio exemplo:

```
public static void main() {
    int i = 0; // <-- variável local, não possui valor padrão.
}
```

Comment: Humm entendi, realmente.
Fiz o teste aqui e é assim mesmo o comportamento.

Muito obrigado amigo!